# webpack --progress Error: write EINVAL

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack

I'm on Windows 10 recently upgraded my node.js to version 7.1.0. I started to get the following error every time I ran the `webpack` command with `--progress` flag.

```
$ webpack --progress
Node Environment: development                                                                                                                                       events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:421:20
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:77:4)
    at Compiler.applyPlugins (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:26:37)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:193:12)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:282:37)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:187:11)
    at E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:275:11
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:60:69)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:272:8)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:267:14)
    at E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
    at E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at E:\Projects\wad\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:43:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:111:15)
```

It works fine without the `--progress` flag and `webpack --progress` was working fine on node.js v6.x.x. Using `webpack --progress` with node v.7.1.0 on the same project but another windows 10 machine also works fine.

What does this error mean?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542) bug

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the version node, use the version 6.9 and success

I had the same problem, and i uninstall node7.1, reboot and install node6.9 and all ok

Answer (score 0):

It seems there a bug at node js v7.1.0 [nodejs/node#9542](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542). Update to the latest version v7.3.0 and everything will be ok.